# Getting input from somewhere other than the command window in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm a beginner in Octave. I need to make a program about vectors and I need user input to draw vectors. I can get input from the command window but I need it to be like the figure window, I want it to pop up. Is there a way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You didn't really specify your plan precisely enough to answer your question. Did you try looking at how to write graphical user interfaces (GUIs) in Octave? See your options here: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/GUI-Development.html#GUI-Development  In general it helps if you provide more information about *exactly* what you are trying to do, and what you have tried so far, and  providing minimal code that directly illustrate the problem are always good (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: look at the `ginput` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use inputdlg()

You can use the [`inputdlg()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Dialog-Box-Functions.html) function to easily create graphical input interfaces for strings and numeric data. Here comes a simple example:

```
myinp = inputdlg({'width','height'},'Please input data!',1,{2.5,320.9})
```

This creates the following dialog:

[image: Dialog created with inputdlg()]

After pressing OK it returns the following results (depending on your input):

```
myinp =
{
  [1,1] = 2.5
  [2,1] = 320.9
}
```

### Use addlistener()

The above solution creates a pop up input dialog, what may not be what you where looking for. To get input based on mouse coordinates you may use the [`addlistener()`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/addlistener.html) function to get the currently selected point coordinates from `axes` object's [`currentpoint`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Axes-Properties.html) property from the current axes whenever it changes.

```
% Create a new axis system in current window
ax = axes();
% Define a listener function that does something with the selected points
listener = @(ah) display(get(ah,'currentpoint'));
% Add Listener to current axis property
addlistener(ax,'currentpoint',listener);
```

Whenever you click to your axis system you will see the current coordinates on console output. Of course this is not a complete solution to your request, there is still some homework to do for you.

### Use ginput()

Using the ginput() function you can collect one or more mouse click positions and the number of the mouse buttons clicked.